# How to correctly initialize the embeding a d3.js resizable chart in a React.js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm testing integrating d3 charts in react components with bi-directionnal communication [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-butterfly-oqdqr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

This [notebook](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-to-embed-a-notebook-in-a-react-app) from the d3 team got me stared and I successfully embed simple charts in react components.

But, in the test case above, I am not able synchronize, on initialisation, the `mwidth` of the d3 chart to my  `this.state.width`.  It only synchronize when I manually move the slider.

My question is how to force (or simulate) the slider mouvement to force the chart update with the correct width, on init ?

The reason for me trying this is that I want to embed d3 charts in resizable and draggable react components. like [those](https://strml.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/0-showcase.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've added `this.refreshID = 0` in the constructor and  `this.refreshID = setInterval(() => this.refresh(), 1);` in `componentDidMount()`

and after changing the state to force rerendering I cancel the callback, that is

```
  refresh() {
    this.setState({width: this.state.width+1});
    clearInterval(this.refreshID)
  }
```

It's not elegant but it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-butterfly-oqdqr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark  (works with chromium)